# Add a navigation property to a plain object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

So I have a viewmodel in my application that looks like:

```
public class CountryVM
    {
        [Key]
        public int CountryID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Country_CountryID")]
        public virtual ICollection<OrganisationVM> Organisations { get; set; }

        public CountryVM(Country country)
        {
            if (country == null) return;

            this.CountryID = country.CountryID;
        }
    }
```

That is seeded by the class:

```
public class Country
    {
        [Key]
        public int CountryID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Organisation> Organisations { get; set; }
    }
```

The other relevant classes are:

```
public class Organisation
{
    [Key]
    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class OrganisationVM
{
    [Key]
    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Country_CountryID")]
    public virtual CountryVM Country { get; set; }
    public int? Country_CountryID { get; set; }
}
```

Now `Organisation` and `Country` are tables in my database and `OrganisationVM` is a view. CountryVM exists only in the application and at the moment EF tries to create a table in my database 'dbo.CountryVMs'.

Is there anyway to hook it up like this so I can use a navigation property in `CountryVM` without it creating tables?

The reason I want to do this is:

I have this code in my web.api controller at the moment:

```
// GET: odata/Country
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<CountryVM> Get()
        {
            var a = db.Countries.ToList().Select<Country, CountryVM>(c => new CountryVM(c)).AsQueryable();
            return a;
        }
```

I was hoping that odata would allow me to use expand and select to select the countryVMs Organisations but it hasn't so far.

Comment: It won't expand because the `CountryVM` constructor only assigns the `CountryID` and not the navigation collection (and is therefore null). If Lazy Loading is enabled in your `DbContext`, it should work as long as your are moving the collection from `Country` to `CountryVM`. Also, calling `ToList()` will effectively materialize all the entries in your tables before the `Select`, keep that in mind.